# How to get out of the Do While loop?

Tags: java

I'm validating a string that does not contain spaces or numbers using regular expressions. But I can't get out of the loop. The string that i entered is correct.

What am I doing wrong? or how to get out of it?

```
boolean bien=true;

do{
  nomc=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese el Nombre: ","Clientes",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  Matcher mat = pat.matcher(nomc);
  if(mat.find()) //esto válida la cadena, si es correcto envía mi cadena a otra clase que estoy usando para guardar el dato
  {
    pm.ficheros(nomc);
  }
  else
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Valor inválido: Evite números y espacios. Intentelo de nuevo","Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
  }
} while(bien);
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Please format your code. Edit > Highlight the code > Ctrl + K

Comment: Set `bien` to false. Or `break;`

Comment: You don't seem to ever change the value of `bien`; its value is always `true`, so the loop will never exit.

Comment: What @ElliottFrisch said. In case `bien` is field and you want to stop this loop from other thread make this field also `volatile` to prevent caching its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `bien` variable to false in order to get out of the while loop in your if clause that guarantee the valid string from

```
if(mat.find()) 
  {
  //this valid string , if successful sends my chain to another class that
 // I am using to save the data
    pm.ficheros(nomc);
   bien = false;
  }
```

so based on following defention

```
do
{
   //Statements
}while(Boolean_expression);
```

> Notice that the Boolean expression appears at the end of the loop, so
>   the statements in the loop execute once before the Boolean is tested.
>
> If the Boolean expression is true, the flow of control jumps back up to do, and the statements in the loop execute again. **This process
>   repeats until the Boolean expression is false.**

in this part of your code:

```
} while(bien);
```

`bien` become `false` so you are out of the do while loop

They called this

**sentinel value**

> In programming, **a special value that is used to terminate a loop**. The
>   sentinel value typically is chosen so as to not be a legitimate data
>   value that the loop will encounter and attempt to perform with. For
>   example, in a loop algorithm that computes non-negative integers, the
>   value "-1" can be set as the sentinel value as the computation will
>   never encounter that value as a legitimate processing output.

[source](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/sentinel_value.html)